LaTeX CV: how to contain text in a ``box?''
I have this:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.5in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{sans}
% \usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% \fontfamily{SansSerif}
% \selectfont

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage
%[ansinew]
[utf8]
{inputenc}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bloo}{rgb}{0.2901960784313726, 0.5764705882352941, 0.8117647058823529}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\textheight=9.75in
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\newcommand{\isep}{-2 pt}
\newcommand{\lsep}{-0.5cm}
\newcommand{\psep}{-0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\pagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{bloo}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.62in}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{{\textbf{#1}}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\hspace{0.5cm}\\[-0.2cm]
\textbf{My Name and details..} \\




\resheading{\textbf{Academic Experience} }\\[\lsep]
\\ \\

%\begin{table}[ht!]
%\begin{center}
\indent \begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.15in} l @{\hskip 0.15in} l @{\hskip 0.15in} l @{\hskip 0.15in} l }
\hline
\textbf{Qualification} & \textbf{School/College} & \textbf{Board/University} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Percentage(\%)} \\
\hline
M-Tech(Computer Science & PITS, Tenali & JNTUk, Kakinada & 2017 & 71.34\\  
and Engineering)\\             
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
%\end{table}
\\ \\

\resheading{\textbf{TECHNICAL SKILLS} }\\[\lsep]
\begin{itemize}
\item \noindent \textbf{Languages:-} Java, JSP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, C, C++, SQL, Python(\textit{Basic Knowledge).}
\end{itemize}


\end{document}

Which produces:

What I want is:

How can I format the text like the box in the middle where it's split on multiple lines?

Sorry, I don’t get you question. Where in your code do you have text that you want to break over several lines? Which box do you mean? The blue ones? I only see a table in the middle. Off-topic: avoid using double backslashes to insert a line break, but use empty lines which will start a new paragraph.

You need to use tcolorbox package. Here is an example code that tells you how you can use in your latex doc.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for sample text

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=cyan!5!white, colframe=cyan!75!black,          
 title=Research Fellow, fonttitle=\bfseries]
 \texbf{Oesophageal Cancer Group} \\
 \textbf{Supervisor: Prof. E. Dawson} \\
\textbf{Dept. Clinical Medicine, Trinity College, University of Dublin,       
 Ireland} \\
 \textbf{May 2011 - Jan 2013} \\
  \\
\textbf{Identification of a Novel Tumour Suppressor Role for CDX2 in  
 Oesophageal Adenocarcinoma} \\
 The exogenous expression of CDX2, an integral protein for the development    
of the premalignant lesion Barrett’s oesophagus, is dramatically reduced 
as oesophageal adenocarcinoma develops. 
\end{tcolorbox}

 \end{document}

This will generate the output as follows. You can tailor as per your desire.

If you don't need dark blue line, remove the title line.

Welcome to tex.sx.
